# Why can't node can't find the static directory?

Tags: node.js

I set up node so that it serves my public folder. Now I am trying to access the files in the public/data/event folder structure but it can't find it.

```
Here is my file structure
public/
      data/
           event/
src/
   scripts/eventController.js
   webserver.js
```

This my eventsController.js file. This file tries to access files in the public/data/event/ folder structure but can't find them.

```
'use strict';

let fs = require('fs');

module.exports.get = function(req, res) {
    let event = fs.readFileSync('../public/data/event/' +
     req.params.id + '.json', 'utf8');

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(event);
};

module.exports.save = function(req, res) {
    let event = req.body;
    fs.writeFileSync('../public/data/event/' + req.params.id +
     '.json', JSON.stringify(event));

    res.send(event);
};

module.exports.getAll = function(req, res) {
    let path = '../public/data/event/';

    let files = [];
    try {
        files = fs.readdirSync(path);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.send('[]');
        res.end();
    }
    let results = '[';
    for (let idx = 0; idx < files.length; idx++) {
        if (files[idx].indexOf('.json') === files[idx].length - 5) {
            results += fs.readFileSync(path + '/' + files[idx]) + ',';
        }
    }
    results = results.substr(0, results.length - 1);
    results += ']';

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(results);
    res.end();
};
```

This is the webserver file, where I server the public folder

```
'use strict';

let express = require('express');

let port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

let path = require('path');
let app = express();
let events = require('./scripts/eventsController');
let rootPath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/../');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(rootPath + '/public'));
app.use('/bower_components', express.static(__dirname + '/../public/lib/'));
app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/data/event/:id', events.get);
app.get('/data/event', events.getAll);
app.post('/data/event/:id', events.save);

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(rootPath + '/public/index.html');
});

app.listen(port, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('There was an error creating the system');
    }
    console.log('running server on port ' + port);
});
```

This is the error that I get from the terminal.[image]

Comment: Slightly offtopic: as a general rule you should *always* sanitize user input before using it to access files on disk, performing database queries (where applicable), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because fs.readFile('public/data/event/') from src/scripts/eventController.js looks for the stuff in 'src/scripts/public/data/event/', not 'public/data/event'. You should go with fs.readFile('../../public/data/event'). Or better yet, always use absolute paths.

Comment: If they're including scripts/eventController.js in the js file in "src", then it'd be fs.readFile('../public/data/event')

Comment: there are 2 types of paths: first type is relative path. relative path, as its name suggests, the path of a file or directory relative to where you're coming from. In your case, src/scripts/eventController.js. If you're at /home, the relative path resolves into /home/src/scripts/eventController.js. Absolute path, on the other hand, doesn't depend on where you're coming from. For windows, "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Project is an absolute path. Similarly for ubuntu, /home/myuser/Desktop/myproject is an absolute path. Because no matter where you are, it always directs the same place.

Answer (score 0):

`public` folder is sibling of `src` folder. You need a absolute path(i.e. begining from root. e.g. /home/username/proj/node/public/) or a correct relative path i.e. `../public`

Comment: How to use absolute path? I edited the question to show a screenshot with the new relative path

Comment: @FernandoAnia added example